# MVC EF Multi-Select dropdown from controller to view only selects one item

Tags: model-view-controller, multi-select

I have a multi-select dropdown, and I'm getting the values from the view to the controller just fine.  In order to get back to my view with the selections the user made, I load up my SelectListItems Selected field based on the array I received.  But, when my view shows up, only the first of the items is selected.

IOW, if I skip the first three items and select the next three, I expect items 3, 4, 5 to be true.  And, when I display the value of the Selected field of those three SelectListItems immediately before constructing the dropdown, they do display as true.  But, only item 3 is showing as checked in the dropdown itself.  When I inspect one of the items that's supposed to be checked, it shows Selected as false.

```
Has 3 - @Model.HasSKUList[3].Selected.ToString()
Has 4 - @Model.HasSKUList[4].Selected.ToString()
Has 5 - @Model.HasSKUList[5].Selected.ToString()
                @Html.DropDownList("HasSKU_ID", Model.HasSKUList, "Select SKU...",
                new { @class = "selectpicker", data_style_base = "form-control", data_width = "100%", data_size = "10", data_dropdown_align_right = "auto", multiple = "multiple", title = "Select SKU(s)...", data_selected_text_format = "count > 3", data_live_search = "true" })
```

I'm at a loss where to look next.

--- Edit ---
I expect people are going to ask to see my controller code.  But, since I have verified that the SelectListItems do, in fact, hold the correct value for Selected, I think the controller code isn't necessary.  Obviously, I'll post it here if I need to.  But, I think it's just a distraction, in this case. @Model.HasSKUList[4].Selected.ToString() does display as true.  Why won't the dropdown multi-select honor that?

Comment: the htmlhelper is for a standard drop-down list... there is none for multi-select dropdown.   I had to workaround this by using javascript to set selected options according to values set in localstorage.  (not a great option really... but it works, and it'll remember the selections without having to re-write links... "asp-route" won't work with arrays...)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a ListBox.

My colleague figured out that, while DropDownList will let you set the multiple parameter, and it'll let you select multiple items, and it'll send those items on submit, MVC really expects DropDownList to select only a single item.  When you call to build a new one, it turns it only selects one of the selected items, and turns all of the others false.

When we changed it to a ListBox, it worked.  It even still looks like a dropdown.

We have another piece of code where the DropDownList has been working for years.  We don't know how or why.  We're just going to not disturb it, for now.  If it ever breaks, we now know the fix.